# which Java data structure to use for key-value pair

Tags: java, data-structures, key-value

I have to store something key value pair:

```
apple - 001
orange - 001
banana - 001
apple - 002
apple - 003
```

(sometime key can be duplicate and sometime value can be duplicate. The entire pair won't be duplicate) please suggest perfect data structure in java.

Comment: You would use a `Map` if there weren't any duplicate keys, but you *sometimes* have those. Write a POJO with two `String`s and store them in a `List`…

Comment: Thanks I thought so, but is there not any DS already present to handle this? 
What about Google's multiMap. I wanted someone to suggest me this or anything more optimal.

Comment: You could search for something already implemented, like a [`org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html).

Comment: What operations are you required to perform on this structure? Iteration only? Seeking through keys? What do expect to get if you seek through keys, a list of values, a list of key-values, etc?

Comment: I am getting list of String separated by '-' (dash) eg(apple-001). first I have to remove the separator and store. Post that I have to update db with condition. only where fruit=('apple' and number='001') or ('apple' and number='002') and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, Set<String>>` like this.

```
static void add(Map<String, Set<String>> map, String key, String value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
}
```

and

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
add(map, "apple", "001");
add(map, "orange", "001");
add(map, "banana", "001");
add(map, "apple", "002");
add(map, "apple", "003");
System.out.println(map);
```

output:

```
{banana=[001], orange=[001], apple=[001, 002, 003]}
```